# Javascript- external library/ file reference

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When I referance my local files like this it works:

```
 var $referances =  $("head"); 

$referances.append('<script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript/geoMaps/Main.js"></script>');
$referances.append('<script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript/geoMaps/Dealer.js"></script>');
$referances.append('<script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript/geoMaps/MapController.js"></script>');
$referances.append('<script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript/geoMaps/Communicator.js"></script>');
```

BUT when I try to include an external library, it doesnt include. Like:

```
$referances.append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js\?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>');
```

What could be the problem here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be you are missing the "</script>" at the end of the string?

Comment: wups, sorry i fixed the questio by adding the tag. But the problem is not that...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false";
$("head").append( script );
```

Comment: This is the better way to do it.

Comment: I tried it before. It still doesnt include the API referenace.. Would the order of inclusion matter in some special case ?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
```

This is not a javascript problem... There are other factors at work here.

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine when I add it to my HTML. But what I want to do is to include the referance through my js file so that whoever uses my application in their page wont have to include it again.

Comment: Wait... you want to store this javascript on your local machine, so that when someone comes to your site it will load from your machine rather than google? Am I correct?

Comment: Nope :) I embed js google maps api into my flash app. And they use the flash app from my server.